# Tkinter Toplevel widget get user input multiple times

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I am trying to get user input using a Toplevel widget in order to create an order but the submit button does not work as expected please assist.

```
def spawn_window(self):
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Available Electronics")
    self.entrytext = StringVar()
    Entry(top, textvariable=self.entrytext).pack()
    button = Button(top, text="Dismiss", command=top.destroy)
    button.pack(side='right')
    submit = Button(top, text ="Submit", command = self.datainput)
    submit.pack(side='left')



def datainput(self):
    input_var = self.entrytext.get()
    self.devices.append(input_var)
```

Comment: What was the desired behavior, and what is the current behavior?

Comment: wanted the text box to turn blank as soon as the submit button was clicked in order to create room for another entry

Comment: Did you try adding the command to remove the old data? How do you expect the widget to know you want it to be cleared?

Comment: I have dealt with it thanks to VRage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"wanted the text box to turn blank as soon as the submit button was clicked in order to create room for another entry" now its clear what you really want!

In your `datainput`-method just clear your stringvar at the end, like this:

```
def datainput(self):
    input_var = self.entrytext.get()
    self.devices.append(input_var)
    self.entrytext.set("")
```

Comment: Thank you for your input

Comment: If this solved your problem, pls mark the answer as correct.